# Spring Data ExampleMatchers by Example

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, query-by-example

I'm trying to understand how to use Spring Data's [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.matchers) capabilities, and am struggling to understand how to use [`ExampleMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/ExampleMatcher.html) and its various `with*` methods. Classic examples of the matcher in use includes snippets like this:

```
Person person = new Person();                          
person.setFirstname("Dave");                           

ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()     
  .withIgnorePaths("lastname")                         
  .withIncludeNullValues()                             
  .withStringMatcherEnding();                          

Example<Person> example = Example.of(person, matcher);
```

For some reason, I just can't wrap my brain around this DSL. Let's take the `Person` example from the docs. Let's say a `Person` entity looks like this:

```
// Pseudo code; omitting JPA annotations for this example
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dob;
    private Long score;

    // Getters, setters & constructor omitted
}
```

Can anyone show me an example of how to construct an `ExampleMatcher` that would allow me to find `Person` records meeting the following criteria:

- First name starts with "*Sme*"; and
- Last name is less than 10 characters long; and
- Date of birth is before 1970-01-01; and
- Score is between 10 and 20, inclusively

**If any of these criteria aren't possible with `ExampleMatcher`, that's fine, but can someone show me which ones are or explain what methods might get me *close* to what I'm looking for?**

Comment: Check the Limitation section in the document you specified,  It says
Only supports starts/contains/ends/regex matching for strings and exact matching for other property types

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran (+1) so in that case can you show me how I would do the following two things: **(1)** filter for first names that start with "Sme", and **(2)** filter for scores that are exactly 50? Thanks again!

Comment: Official Documentation will be helpful: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.matchers

Comment: @pvpkiran In order to search records which have firstname given as an input in a string say s and score given as an input in a Integer i how the  matcher can be written ? Basically I want as for any string for any field in person class how the search example can be created.
 Using Example.of(person, ExampleMatcher.matching())

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get records with firstName starting with "Sme" and score=50

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("Sme");
person.setScore(50L);
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
    .withMatcher("firstName", startsWith())
    .withMatcher("score", exact());

Example<History> example = Example.of(person, matcher);
personRepository.findAll(example)
```

Comment: Use this code for new version
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
       .withMatcher("firstName", new GenericPropertyMatcher().startsWith())
       .withMatcher("score", new GenericPropertyMatcher().exact());

Comment: I am example matcher to filter some values, but how to use this to filter a column with a list. Means as long as any row contains the column value in the list. I can use @Query but using with other fields checking null would be difficult to maintain

Comment: @ThinkTank, import static org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.startsWith;

Comment: any idea how to match a collection, kind of $in?

Comment: HI @NextDeveloper did you find the solution for $in clause? if you did, can you please post the solution