# Cant make ExampleMatcher filter work in Spring Boot with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, rest, intellij-idea

I am learning how to make a REST API with Spring Boot and MongoDB, but i cant figure out how to use the Example Matcher to filter the results.

If I just do

```
Page<Movie> result = movieRepository.findAll(request);
```

Everything works fine and I get the expected result.

[image]

But when I tried to add a filter, nothing worked. To try to start from the ground up, I tried to implemented so it didnt filter anything out, but even then nothing worked.

I am kinda lost here because I really dont know what I am doing wrong, so I would appreciate any help here.

Here is my code:

## Movie.java

```
@Document("films")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Movie {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String overview;
    private String tagline;
    private Collection collection;
    private List<String> genres;
    private Date releaseDate;
    private List<String> keywords;
    private List<Producer> producers;
    private List<Crew> crew;
    private List<Cast> cast;
    private List<Resource> resources;
    private Long budget;
    private Status status;
    private Integer runtime;
    private Long revenue;

    public Movie() {
    }
}
```

## MovieController.java

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<?> get(
            @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "14") int size,
            @RequestParam(name = "sort", defaultValue = "") List<String> sort,
            @RequestParam(name = "clave", required = false) List<String> clave,
            @RequestParam(name = "genre", required = false) List<String> genre,
            @RequestParam(name = "estreno", required = false) String estreno,
            @RequestParam(name = "title", required = false) String title) {
        List<Sort.Order> criteria = sort.stream().map(string -> {
                    if (string.startsWith("a")) {
                        return Sort.Order.asc(string.substring(1));
                    } else if (string.startsWith("-")) {
                        return Sort.Order.desc(string.substring(1));
                    } else return null;
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Optional<Page<Movie>> filmFound;

        if (estreno != null) {
            String[] parts = estreno.split("/");
        }
        filmFound = movies.getAllMovies(page, size, Sort.by(criteria), clave, genre, estreno, title);
        if (filmFound.isPresent()) {
            Page<Movie> data = filmFound.get();
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .body(filmFound.get());
        }
        return null;
```

## MovieService.java

```
public Optional<Page<Movie>> getAllMovies(int page, int size, Sort sort, List<String> clave, List<String> genero, String estreno, String title) {
        Pageable request = PageRequest.of(page, size, sort);

        ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll();
        Example<Movie> filter = Example.of(
                new Movie(),
                matcher
        );

        Page<Movie> result = movieRepository.findAll(filter, request);

        if (result.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No result");
            return Optional.empty();
        } else{
            return Optional.of(result);
        }
```

*The output is just a blank screen, when in theory it should be the same as the first picture
*

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575300/spring-data-examplematchers-by-example ?

Comment: I already did, but it just doesnt work. It always returns an empty list the moment I add a filter to findAll(). I am honestly very confused of why it doesnt work @JackyLiu-JetBrains